# C++ Strange output during extraction of integers using cin.ignore()

Tags: c++

The following program expects user input in the mixed fraction format 'whole_numbernumerator/denominator' and assigns values to respective variables.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int whole, numerator, denominator;

    cout << "Input format: i<space>n/d" << endl;

    cin >> whole;
    cin.ignore(1000, ' ');
    cin >> numerator;
    cin.ignore(1000, '/');
    cin >> denominator;

    cout << whole << endl;
    cout << numerator << endl;
    cout << denominator << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Input1:**
123 345/678 
**Output1:**
123
345
678

**Input2**:
1111111111 1111111111/1111111111
**Output2:**
1111111111
1111111111
1111111111

**Input3:**
2222222222 2222222222/222222222
**Output3:**
2147483647
0
0

I haven't been able to figure out why the program doesn't work for Input3.

Comment: Please, can you change `int` for `long` and post the result?

Comment: @h3nr1x, Both of those are 4 bytes for me. For specific byte values I recommend using the `[u]intx_t` types, where u is optional (for unsigned) and x represents the number of bits (8, 16, 32, 64).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overflowing the maximum value for a 32-bit integer (2^31-1 ~= 2.147b). Once this happens, `cin` doesn't work properly until you clear the flag. You should be checking for errors, but a short-term solution is to make your number unsigned, or use a 64-bit one, like `int64_t`. You also don't need to ignore the space, as `cin` will skip it by default.

You can implement something like what's found [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.3) to ensure valid input, but it needs to be tailored to fit your specific input format. Perhaps encapsulating the three into a single type with an overloaded operator that inputs each with respect to the formatting would make the syntax fit more nicely, so you could replace `age` in the example with a `MixedNumber` object.

I would see something like this as a versatile method:

```
template <typename T> //any type will work
void getValidInput (T &var, std::string prompt = "Input: ") {
    while ((std::cout << prompt) && !(std::cin >> var)) { //if cin fails...
        std::cin.clear();                 //clear flag and discard bad input
        std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cout << "Invalid input; please re-enter.\n"; //let the user know
    } 
}
```

Then you could just have your program as follows:

```
struct MixedNumber { //a data structure, so it's like using plain variables
    int64_t whole; 
    int64_t numerator;
    int64_t denominator;
};

std::istream &operator>> (std::istream &in, MixedNumber &num) { //so cin works
    in >> num.whole >> num.numerator;
    in.ignore(); //yes, you could enforce the format a bit more
    in >> num.denominator;
    return in;
}

int main() {
    MixedNumber num; //easy to "make" a mixed number, a constructor works well too
    getValidInput (num, "Input format: i<space>n/d: "); 
    std::cout << num.whole << '\n' << num.numerator << '\n' << num.denominator;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I am not quite into templates yet. It will be a good reference for me.

Comment: @yang5, It's just so that it works with *any* type (as long as it has `operator>>` working with it). You could technically remove the `template` line and replace `T &` with `MixedNumber &`, but this way you can reuse it without changing it! I actually just took the whole code and wouldn't you know it, there were no errors (apart from the includes)! That's a first :p I actually wrote each part in here independently without testing it.